# Meteor MongoDb collection not accessible on client side

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

I have created a collection which should be accessible to client side and server side. But when I try to use it in browser it gives me undefined.

```
var lists = new Meteor.Collection("Lists");
//lists.insert({Category:"DVDs", items: {Name:"Mission Impossible",Owner:"me",LentTo:"Alice"}});
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  // counter starts at 0
  Session.setDefault('counter', 0);

  Template.hello.helpers({
    counter: function () {
      return Session.get('counter');
    }
  });

  Template.hello.events({
    'click button': function () {
      // increment the counter when button is clicked
      Session.set('counter', Session.get('counter') + 1);
    }
  });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
  });
}
```

Now when I use lists in client side browser console it gives me undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the collection without var keyword. It will make a global variable accessible in the whole application. And define collections uppercase:

```
Lists = new Meteor.Collection("lists");
```

It's a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

If you has removed `autopublish` package, you should subscribe on collection at the client-side

```
Meteor.subscribe("lists");
```

publish it at server-side

```
Meteor.publish("lists", function () {
  return Lists.find({});
});
```

and use lowercase for collection name.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.